# Assigned template vs ?template=myTemplate

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates

I recently tested a new template for a site (University by Shape5). I tried to get a quick preview before setting the template as default by adding `?template=university` to the url. But the template was not rendered correctly (no main menu, text-width 100%, no footer etc.). It was not until I assigned the template as default that it was rendered propperly.

So my question is: Is there any difference between how Joomla renders a template when using `?template=myTemplate`, as opposed to assigning the template to a menu item (or as default template)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My reading of the source is that the template parameter overrides the template name after Joomla has loaded the template settings. So, your university template got the settings for the default template and probably didn't have the correct information to be able to display.

See https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/cms/application/site.php#L420

Comment: that's interesting

Comment: +1 Very interesting. It seems to happen with many Shape5 templates, haven't seen this problem with other template providers (so far).